# PhpStorm not listening to breakpoints

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I have been struggling for hours regarding Xdebug and PhpStorm but I cannot get it to work, I have done the following:

1. Installed Xdebug `sudo apt-get install php-xdebug`

2. Edited the php.ini file `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 512
xdebug.file_link_format = phpstorm://open?%f:%l
```

3. Check the version `php --version`

```
PHP 7.0.33-10+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Aug  7 2019 09:50:44) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.33-10+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.7.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by Derick Rethans
```

4. Restart the service `sudo service apache2 restart`

5. Configure PhpStorm

Go through - `Settings >> Languages & Frameworks >> PHP`

Set the PHP Interpreter, to do so; click on three dots `[...]` button

On the new window; click on plus `[+]` button and select `/usr/bin/php` from suggestion popup.

[image]

Save and close this window and select the interpreter

I set the breakpoint and started listening

[image]

I access the url `http://localhost/debug/file.php` and nothing happens. I honestly don't have much more to say, I will share some files you might see what I have wrong.

What files should I share? This installation is based on https://gist.github.com/thomascys/7bf160bfe354eb74a8bb8b75e19038f4

/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 512
xdebug.file_link_format = phpstorm://open?%f:%l
```

Comment: 1) Check that Xdebug installed and enabled; check its' settings (from `phpinfo()` output). 2) If all good there enable xdebug logging and collect log for such unsuccessful debug session. **P.S.** Based on the info you've provided so far, I do not see why Xdebug should try to debug your code. I do not see any "debug all requests" option set, neither you have mentioned any cookie/param to tell Xdebug "debug this"... Check docs: 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-with-phpstorm-ultimate-guide.html and 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have setup PHP in PHPStorm, check your settings under "Languages and Frameworks", disclose the "PHP" entry and select the "Debug" option. The settings revealed include a link named "Validate debugger configuration on the Web Server." Click on it and attempt to validate. It will give you more details on PHP and XDEBUG. If validation passes then click on "Install browser toolbar or bookmarklets." and follow the directions. This adds bookmarks lets that will have your browser submit page request with the necessary cookies to trigger xdebug.